# Multidimensional Array: display data only where the same key from different arrays have the same value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array returned to me from a web-service call. The array looks like below:

```
$flights_data = array
(
   'departure_trip_data' => array
    (
       0 => array('departure_date'=>'Mar 25, 2015', 'ticket_class'='Y'),
       1 => array('departure_date'=>'Mar 25, 2015', 'ticket_class'='B'),
       2 => array('departure_date'=>'Mar 25, 2015', 'ticket_class'='H'),
   ),
   'return_trip_data' => array
   (
       0 => array('departure_date'=>'Mar 28, 2015', 'ticket_class'='Y'),
       1 => array('departure_date'=>'Mar 28, 2015', 'ticket_class'='B'),
       2 => array('departure_date'=>'Mar 28, 2015', 'ticket_class'='K'),
   )
);
```

And I'm processing it thus:

```
<?php
$departure_trips = $flight_data['departure_trip_data'];
$return_trips    = $flight_data['return_trip_data'];
?>

<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($departure_trips); $i++): ?>
<?php
   $curr_departure_trip = $departure_trips[$i];
   $curr_return_trip    = $return_trips[$i];
?>

<td>Departure Date : <?php echo $curr_departure_trip['departure_date']; ?></td>
<td>Return Date    : <?php echo $curr_return_trip['departure_date']; ?></td>
<td>Ticket Class   : <?php echo $curr_departure_trip['ticket_class']; ?> </td>
<!-- long lines of plain HTML code goes here -->

<?php endfor; ?>
```

My problem is: how do I display the data for only those cases where the `ticket_class` values are the same in both the `departure_trip_data` array and the `return_trip_data` array? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after the update of your question I guess you don't want to wrap the entire HTML block inside an if-block. To avoid this, just turn it around:

```
if($curr_departure_trips['ticket_class'] != $curr_return_trips['ticket_class']) 
    continue;
```

This way you go to the next row if the ticket class is different.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if i got this right,

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($departure_trips); $i++)
{
   $curr_departure_trip = $departure_trips[$i];
   $curr_return_trip    = $return_trips[$i];

   if($curr_departure_trips['ticket_class'] == $curr_return_trips['ticket_class']) {
   echo '<td>Departure Date : '. $curr_departure_trip['departure_date']. '</td>';
   echo '<td>Return Date : '.    $curr_return_trip['departure_data']. '</td>';
   echo '<td>Ticket Class : '.   $curr_departure_trip['ticket_class']. '</td>';
   }

}
```

Comment: I know of that. But the issues is, I'm using this syntax: `for($i = 0; $i < count($departure_trips); $i++):` and then inside I have a very long plain HTML code. if I decide to go by the `if` test, it will defeat my purpose in using the format just stated.

Comment: I dont get it, what is the problem with this? The use of `echo`?

Comment: There's no issue with echo, just that I have a long string of HTML code in the for loop. I have updated my code so you can get a clearer picture of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I added an answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

you can use nested loop to loop through the array and compare one by one and if a match is found process it

Comment: Yes, I could do that. But that might add to the processing time. I already have a lot of loops in the code and I want to limit the number of loops. I am wondering if PHP has any built-in function to handle such scenario. By the way, I didn't downvote you, don't know who did. Thanks for the help.